# React Native, Component Exception in fetching data within JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I made some modification on this react native code to read data from JSON file (data.js), which keeps throwing error:
Component Exception
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.details.country')
my code is:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet,Image , TouchableOpacity,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
    import datas from '../data.js';

    // create a component
    class Story extends Component {
        //state={
        //    datas: datas
        //}
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { selectedButton: null , datas: datas}
            //this.state = { selectedButton: null };
            this.selectionOnPress = this.selectionOnPress.bind(this);
        }
        selectionOnPress(userType) {
            this.setState({ selectedButton: userType });
        }
        getCriteria(){
            return this.state.datas.map(data => {
                
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectionOnPress(this.props.detail.country)}>
                            <Text style={{
                                backgroundColor:
                                    this.state.selectedButton === this.props.detail.country ? "red" : "grey"
                            }}>
                                <Text style={styles.btnSV}>{this.props.detail.country}</Text>
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                
            })
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                
                {this.getCriteria()}
                
                </ScrollView>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    // define your styles
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
        }
    });
    //make this component available to the app
    export default Story;
```

data.js file content data with special format looks like JSON:

```
let data export default data = [
{
    id: 1,
    country: "USA",
},
{
    id: 2,
    country: "UK",
},
{
    id: 3,
    country: "India",
},
{
    id: 4,
    country: "Russia",
},
{
    id: 5,
    country: "France",
}]
```

How to fix this error? please

Comment: `this.state = { selectedButton: null }` in the constructor overwrites the `state={ datas: datas }` you have elsewhere. Just put them both in the constructor as `this.state = { selectedButton: null , datas: datas}` (and you can simplify `{ datas: datas }` as just `{ datas }`)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've followed your instructions and I got new Error: undefined is not object ('_this2.props.details.country').

Comment: Well, that's a new error - so the previous one at least seems to be fixed. You probably want to ask a new question about this one - but it seems that you're not passing in a `details` prop, somewhere where you're rendering this component.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I did update my Question so tell me how to fix this Error please.

Comment: As previously mentioned, you must not be passing a `details` prop in. It's impossible to say more without seeing how you are rendering this in its parent component.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I found this code: detail={data} key={data.id} where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this on datas.js.

```
const datas = [
{
    id: 1,
    country: "USA",
},
{
    id: 2,
    country: "UK",
},
{
    id: 3,
    country: "India",
},
{
    id: 4,
    country: "Russia",
},
{
    id: 5,
    country: "France",
}]

export default datas;
```